# Adding library or module to the spring boot project using Intellj

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

[image: l]

I am new to spring boot, I am trying to separate the layer. I am trying to create library and add a dependency to the Rest API.

**Data Layer**

Communicate with the Database

**Service Layer**

Bussiness logic

**Application Layer**

Email or other application service

I am using IntellJ IDE, how can I achieve this.

Reference

https://www.baeldung.com/jsf-spring-boot-controller-service-dao

https://medium.com/@RogelioOrts/layered-architecture-spring-boot-af7dc071d2b5

https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-layers.html

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the initializer https://start.spring.io/ to setup the spring boot project depends on your requirement.  This will give you the structure to setup the controller ->Service and DAO layer

Comment: I am looking for different layers. So that I can communicate effectively with different layer

Comment: I got a reference of https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/#setting-up-the-library-project but quite didn't understand...